# Rails: corret way of validate number of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my case, `user` has many `categories`, and I want to prevent user to delete his last `category`, this is what I did in `Categories#destroy`:

```
  def destroy
    if current_user.categories.count > 1
      @category.destroy
      redirect_to categories_url
    else
      flash[:category_notice] = "Cannot destroy the last category"
      redirect_to categories_url
    end
  end
```

Obviously, this solves the problem. But I want to know if there is a corret way of doing it? Or this is just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer to do it in the model (thatway you can prevent destroying the last record when you are working on the console too).
For ex you can use [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) inside your Category-model:

```
before_destroy: check_if_last

def check_if_last
    raise "Can't destroy last category!" if self.user.categories.count  == 1
end
```

**EDIT:** To avoid race condition on user object, [locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) should do.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not guarantee, that the last category will not be removed due to a condition race.

Comment: @BroiSatse, I believe [locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) can be used to avoid race condition? I guess both, optimistic and pessimistic locking are possible here.

Comment: How can I configure the `error` message? I need `I18n`.

Comment: Just add your error-message to your translation file and replace error message string in `check_if_last` method with `I18n.t('your.path.to.error_message.in.tranlsationfile')`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a counter onto the user.  So a user has a `categories_count` field, with a default of 0.

```
add_column :users, :categories_count, :integer, default: 0
```

then

```
class User
  has_many :categories
end

class Category
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

You might want to use [reset_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters):

```
User.find_each do |u|
 User.reset_counters(u.id, :categories)
end
```

To set the counters to the appropriate values.

Then you can do

```
if current_user.categories_count > 1
  @category.destroy
  redirect_to categories_url
else
  flash[:category_notice] = "Cannot destroy the last category"
  redirect_to categories_url
end
```

This way the count is cached and it saves you a query.  It's not much of a difference and your way is fine.